# How Do I Read Chrome Cookies File?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, cookies

> I would like to note that I've opened read and tried all the solutions from all the posts on StackOverflow to try and achieve my goal with absolutely no luck at all, tried using SH, Python, CMD, C# and even PowerShell all of the codes were outdated and did not work for me

**Story Goes:**

I've reinstalled Windows and wanted to backup Chrome Cookies just so I won't have to login into all of the websites again, I simply went to:

```
'/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cookies/Cookies'
```

and saved the file to my USB, Now I would like to read some of the cookies from that file so I can restore them one by one since I already have Cookies I need on my current Chrome.

---

**What I know:**

The Cookies file is based on SQL-LITE3 database which is encrypted, I figured ok there must be a way to at least view the database tables columns and etc with some kind of a sql viewer but I can't find any, I would love any hints on this one, Any method. Thanks!

Comment: The main goal is to view a specific website cookie I need and forge a JSON format out of it so I can use a Chrome Extension called EditThisCookie and import that specific cookie into a site I lost access to

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I no longer think this should be allowed to do, this can be used by bad actors and chrome needs to block it, luckily I just checked and it looks like they already did, the cookies no longer stored in chrome default user data folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really sure if this is what you are looking for. I am also trying to use existing cookies but need to decrypt them first. This script will at least load the cookie database and let you pull values. It is quite broad and will pull thousands of lines. Maybe someone will find it useful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3
import gzip

filename="\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies" #EDIT ME
connection = sqlite3.connect(filename)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cookies;")
results = cursor.fetchall()

for r in results:
    site=r[1]
    type=r[2]
    code=str(r[12])
    vSite=site.find("ENTER WEBSITE")
    if vSite > -1:
        print(site+': '+'\t'+type+'\n'+'\n'+code+'\n')
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Amazing solution, Yeah it's all encrypted idk what I was thinking back then.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to view Chrome Cookies since they are encrypted and you have to decrypt them.