# Will Google lock the file of the currently logged in user?

Tags: python

When I tried to obtain cookies from Google using Python, I found that the currently logged in user's NetWork folder was occupied and the administrator did not have permission to access this file.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies'
```

Comment: You don't need to repeat yourself, and please lay off the boldface. It doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using

Comment: What do you mean by "Google"?  Google is a company.  Are you referring to the Google Chrome browser perchance?

Comment: And what do you mean by "occupied"?

Comment: This sounds like normal Windows behavior.  A file that is open for writing its locked by the OS.   But you might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831923/how-do-i-read-chrome-cookies-file

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, when I am using browser_ Cookie3 prompted Permission denied when attempting to obtain a cookie from Chrome

Comment: Actually, you didn't mention it earlier.  You said "Google".  That's a company ... or a search engine.  Anyway, if the file is locked or set so that Admin can't access it, there will be good reasons; e.g. privacy, security and/or preventing the cookie store from being corrupted.   (FWIW, the cookie store is an encrypted sqllite3 database ... according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831923/how-do-i-read-chrome-cookies-file)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now this method is also ineffective.It will prompt "sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file"

Comment: I expressed it incorrectly, it should be chrome

Comment: For example, when I log in to user 1, the cookie file stored locally in Chrome cannot be read. However, when I close the browser of the logged in user, it can be accessed. However, it was still possible a few days ago, and now it has become inaccessible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another thread. It works for me. I do have to do this every time I restart the computer though. I'm not sure if there is a way to set it to stay that way.

[Unable to Open Cookie File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440733/unable-to-open-cookie-file)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).